# SharePoint Global Navigation Tabs Security

Tags: permissions, navigation

Im having different tabs on the global navigation of site and there will be different groups who will be having rights to different tabs of the application. On click of the tab respective contents will open up. My requirement is only person with required access should be able to see the required pages and contents.

Please provide a best way to achieve this type of security permission in SharePoint.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Abraham

Answer (score 2):

Abraham,

You will need to activate "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" (Site Settings -> Under Site Collection Settings -> Site collection features)

This will give you Navigation settings under Look and Feel (Site Settings -> Under Look and Feel -> Navigation) as shown in below image:

[image]

Now inside Navigation, you have control over Global Navigation... And you can do "Audience Targeting" on your Navigation... This will show you a window like below:

[image]

If you select any of the "Tab"|"Global Navigation Item" and click Edit - you have this Audience Target option where you can define the Group for which the Tab is visible!

**NOTE:**
1- You should have User Profile Service up and running before you can use Audience Targeting
2- I had everything in Arabic, so alignment and text is weird.. Ignore that please! :)

Comment: Mark the answer if it was helpful :)